# Confusion in a programming example

Tags: c++

Currently I am reading "Accelerated C++" and in an example in chapter 4, a function is written as to read from the input stream, which is as follows:

```
istream &read ( istream & in , vector < double >& work )
{
    if ( in ) {            // why it is needed ?
        double x ;         // x denotes the grade
        work.clear ( );    // why we need it ?
        while ( in >> x )
            work.push_back ( x );
        in.clear ( );      // understandable.
    }
    return in;
} 

int main ( )
{
    vector < double > homework;
    vector <double> schoolwork;
    read ( cin , homework );
    read ( cin , schoolwork );
    // code for output
}
```

Why is this needed:

```
if ( in ){.....}
```

Because `while ( in >> x )` also plays that same role because when there is error (type mismatch, for example) in input stream then it will stop taking input and stream remains in error state, which is further cleared using `in.clear()`. So that it can work for vector `schoolwork` after `homework`.

1. So why `if ( in )` is needed although we have `while ( in >> x )` which can perform the same?
2. Secondly, I am very much confused with `work.clear( )`.

   Why we need to clear the vector itself, although we are passing it with reference?

Comment: `work.clear()` to make sure you start on an empty vector, since you're adding to (`push_back()`) to it... it might not be what it is desired in some cases... but to me is a likely explanation

Comment: did you mean `vector < double >&work`?

Comment: @jsantander but we are passing it with reference?secondly if next time we need to writeto same vector it becomes impossible.

Comment: @ChrisDrew sorry , yes you are write i have edited.

Comment: @Bayant_singh if you're doing `vector<double> work` you're passing it **by value** then the whole function is wrong since the work vector modifications will not be visible outside. If you're doing `vector<double> &work` then you're passing it **by reference**. It is certainly true that you cannot accumulate, but as I said, it is a possibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. To leave the vector unchanged, rather than clearing it, if the stream is bad.
2. The behaviour of the function is to replace the contents of `work` with the input. Without the `clear`, it would append the input. The vague function name, and lack of documentation, make it unclear which is intended unless you read the code - renaming the function (e.g. `replace`), or returning a vector by value rather than making the caller create one, would help with this ambiguity.

Comment: but the while ( in >> x ) can also acts same for if ( in ) so if we dont use if ( in ) where the difference comes.

Comment: @Bayant_singh: But `while (in >> x)` happens *after* clearing the vector. As I said, the `if` means the vector is left unchanged if the stream is bad to begin with.